# Ward model implementation: specular component too weak

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, webgl

I'm trying to implement the Ward shading model, the anisotropic, computationally efficient version:

[image]
[image]

This is how I made it:

```
float alphaX=0.5, alphaY=0.5; // asinotropic roughness
float minFloat= 1.e-6; 

vec4 Ward(vec3 L, vec3 N, vec3 V)
{
    vec3 H= normalize(L+V);
    float NdotL= max(dot(N,L),0.0);
    float NdotV= max(dot(N,V),0.0);

    vec3 e= vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    vec3 T= normalize(cross(N,e));
    vec3 B= normalize(cross(N,T));
    float HdotT= max(dot(H,T),0.0);
    float HdotB= max(dot(H,B),0.0);
    float HdotN= max(dot(H,N),0.0);

    float beta= -2.0 * ( pow(HdotN/alphaX, 2.0) + pow(HdotB/alphaY,2.0) ) / (1.0 + HdotN);
    float den= max(minFloat, 4.0 * pi * alphaX * alphaY * sqrt(NdotL * NdotV) );
    vec4 specular= Ps * 1.0/den * exp(beta);
    return (Pd + specular) * NdotL;
}
```

But I get a result similar to a lambertian surface or Oren-Nayar model, where the specular component is absent:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the first `HdotN` in `beta` be `HdotT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by just changing the `e` vector to `(0,0,-1)`. I also needed to clamp the returned color:

```
return clamp((Pd + specular) * NdotL, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a "fixed" render result to the answer? :)

Comment: Added it, @KromStern .

Answer (score 0):

Your alpha values are too high.  You have them both set to 0.5, which represents a very rough surface, which will have a very broad and diffuse specular highlight.  Try setting them to something like 0.01, and you should get a smaller, hotter highlight.

The alpha values in the Ward distribution work similarly to the "m" value in the Beckmann distribution - they control the typical slope of microfacets, so small values correspond to smooth, glossy surfaces.

Comment: Even with very low values of anisotropic roughness I don't see any part of the teapot shining, like it does with Blinn-Phong model.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri What is `Ps` set to?  Otherwise, your code looks good to me. Although you should probably leave out the factor of pi in the denominator (see [to pi or not to pi](http://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/pi-or-not-to-pi-in-game-lighting-equation/)).

Comment: Ps is the specular component (specular material color multiplied for the specular light), Pd the diffuse component.

Comment: I removed the pi term and it's like before: the specular component is too low.